# Rest Api Parameter Validation best Practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, rest

Im a bit confused about the Parameter Validation in a node.js Rest Api.
I wrote a little Middleware which switch through all routes like this

```
switch (req.route.path) {
  case '/checkRequirements':
    req.assert('location', 'Invalid Location Array').notEmpty()
    req.assert('platform', 'Invalid Platform').notEmpty()
    req.assert('version', 'Invalid Version').notEmpty()
    break

  case 'login':
    req.assert('uuid', 'Invalid UUID').notEmpty().isUUID()
    req.assert('fbToken', 'Invalid Facebook Token').notEmpty()
    req.assert('location', 'Invalid Location Array').notEmpty()
    break
}
```

if the the validation pass it goes with next to the api function. But my Co Worker told me i should not do it like this. Instead i should add the validation in the route function it self. He said we should do it like this cause of Latency. Is there a best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do this sort of validation in each corresponding route function.  It's more maintainable, since all logic is in one place.  Otherwise, if you change a route function, you need to remember to go and update your middleware.